# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am classifying music from audio files by genre like jazz, classical, western, pop etc. For this I am training a machine learning model and I am testing with the audio file. I wrote a script which is giving good results. I wrote a script to create a dataset, in this code i am getting an error.

**The error**:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "CreateDataset.py", line 124, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "CreateDataset.py", line 38, in main
>     dataset_numpy = scaler.fit_transform(dataset_numpy)
>   File "/root/twitter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 517, in fit_transform
>     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
>   File "/root/twitter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 308, in fit
>     return self.partial_fit(X, y)
>   File "/root/twitter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 334, in partial_fit
>     estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
>   File "/root/twitter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 441, in check_array
>     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
> array=[].
> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
> ```

**The code is as follows:**

```
import librosa
import numpy
import pandas
import os
import sklearn
import config


def main():
    samp_rate = config.CreateDataset.SAMPLING_RATE
    frame_size = config.CreateDataset.FRAME_SIZE
    hop_size = config.CreateDataset.HOP_SIZE
    dataset_dir = config.CreateDataset.DATASET_DIRECTORY
    sub_folders = get_subdirectories(dataset_dir)

    labels = []
    is_created = False

    print("Extracting features from audios...")
    # global dataset_numpy
    dataset_numpy = []
    for sub_folder in sub_folders:
        print(".....Working in folder:", sub_folder)
        sample_arrays = get_sample_arrays(dataset_dir, sub_folder, samp_rate)
        for sample_array in sample_arrays:
            row = extract_features(sample_array, samp_rate, frame_size, hop_size)
            if not is_created:
                dataset_numpy = numpy.array(row)
                is_created = True
            elif is_created:
                dataset_numpy = numpy.vstack((dataset_numpy, row))

            labels.append(sub_folder)

    print("Normalizing the data...")
    scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    dataset_numpy = scaler.fit_transform(dataset_numpy)

    Feature_Names = ['meanZCR', 'stdZCR', 'meanSpecCentroid', 'stdSpecCentroid', 'meanSpecContrast', 'stdSpecContrast',
                     'meanSpecBandwidth', 'stdSpecBandwidth', 'meanSpecRollof', 'stdSpecRollof',
                     'meanMFCC_1', 'stdMFCC_1', 'meanMFCC_2', 'stdMFCC_2', 'meanMFCC_3', 'stdMFCC_3',
                     'meanMFCC_4', 'stdMFCC_4', 'meanMFCC_5', 'stdMFCC_5', 'meanMFCC_6', 'stdMFCC_6',
                     'meanMFCC_7', 'stdMFCC_7', 'meanMFCC_8', 'stdMFCC_8', 'meanMFCC_9', 'stdMFCC_9',
                     'meanMFCC_10', 'stdMFCC_10', 'meanMFCC_11', 'stdMFCC_11', 'meanMFCC_12', 'stdMFCC_12',
                     'meanMFCC_13', 'stdMFCC_13'
                     ]

    dataset_pandas = pandas.DataFrame(dataset_numpy, columns=Feature_Names)

    dataset_pandas["genre"] = labels
    dataset_pandas.to_csv("data_set.csv", index=False)
    print("Data set has been created and sent to the project folder!")

def get_subdirectories(a_dir):
    return [name for name in os.listdir(a_dir)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(a_dir, name))]


def get_sample_arrays(dataset_dir, folder_name, samp_rate):
    path_of_audios = librosa.util.find_files(dataset_dir + "/" + folder_name)
    audios = []
    for audio in path_of_audios:
        x, sr = librosa.load(audio, sr=samp_rate, duration=5.0)
        audios.append(x)
    audios_numpy = numpy.array(audios)
    return audios_numpy


def extract_features(signal, sample_rate, frame_size, hop_size):
    zero_crossing_rate = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(y=signal, frame_length=frame_size, hop_length=hop_size)
    spectral_centroid = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=signal, sr=sample_rate, n_fft=frame_size,
                                                          hop_length=hop_size)
    spectral_contrast = librosa.feature.spectral_contrast(y=signal, sr=sample_rate, n_fft=frame_size,
                                                          hop_length=hop_size)
    spectral_bandwidth = librosa.feature.spectral_bandwidth(y=signal, sr=sample_rate, n_fft=frame_size,
                                                            hop_length=hop_size)
    spectral_rolloff = librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(y=signal, sr=sample_rate, n_fft=frame_size, hop_length=hop_size)
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal, sr=sample_rate, n_fft=frame_size, hop_length=hop_size)

    return [

        numpy.mean(zero_crossing_rate),
        numpy.std(zero_crossing_rate),
        numpy.mean(spectral_centroid),
        numpy.std(spectral_centroid),
        numpy.mean(spectral_contrast),
        numpy.std(spectral_contrast),
        numpy.mean(spectral_bandwidth),
        numpy.std(spectral_bandwidth),
        numpy.mean(spectral_rolloff),
        numpy.std(spectral_rolloff),

        numpy.mean(mfccs[1, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[1, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[2, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[2, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[3, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[3, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[4, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[4, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[5, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[5, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[6, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[6, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[7, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[7, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[8, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[8, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[9, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[9, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[10, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[10, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[11, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[11, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[12, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[12, :]),
        numpy.mean(mfccs[13, :]),
        numpy.std(mfccs[13, :]),
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I resolve the error?

**My config.py file looks like this:**

```
# --- CONFIGURATIONS FOR Convert_to_wav --- #
class ConvertWav:
  # Path of the song folder which will be used for wav converting
  CONVERT_DIRECTORY = "./TestFiles"

  # File extension in song folder
  FILE_TYPE = "au"

# --- CONFIGURATIONS FOR Create_Dataset_as_csv --- #
class CreateDataset:
    # Path of GTZAN dataset
    DATASET_DIRECTORY = "./TrainFiles/"

    # Sampling rate (Hz)
    SAMPLING_RATE = 22050

    # Frame size (Samples)
    FRAME_SIZE = 2048

    # Hop Size (Samples)
    HOP_SIZE = 512


class Test:
    # Path for test data
    TEST_DATA_PATH = "./TestFiles/"
```

Comment: Could you try to add `dataset_numpy = []` in the same line the `# global dataset_numpy` is? It seems that your loop is not running, therefore the `dataset_numpy` is not being set. If the `dataset_numpy = []` works, you need to fix the `for sub_folder in sub_folders:` loop.

Comment: Your `dataset_numpy` is an empty list. My claim still holds: either you do not have any `sub_folders` or you did not extract any features.